# BigQuery select error. Error: Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

When i run a the following query i get this error: Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
It only happened when i run a query that return a timestamp and a column name **"profile"** and only if i try to insert the result into a **Destination Table**.

```
SELECT 'helllo' as [profile], 
TIMESTAMP( '2014-10-22' ) as date_out
```

i have tried to change the column name from "profile" to something else and it works, but i really need it to be profile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the expected result when I try your query with "allowLargeResults" disabled, both in the web UI and with the 'bq' command-line tool:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| profile |      date_out       |
+---------+---------------------+
| helllo  | 2014-10-22 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

If "allowLargeResults" is enabled, however, this produces an internal error. This is a bug in BigQuery, and I've filed against the team. Is it possible for you to work around the issue by disabling allowLargeResults?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this bug only occurs when you try to insert the results into a destination table. Did you try to do it with the destination table?

Comment: Yes, this still works for me with a destination table. I'm able to both create the table using this query, as well as append rows to it. The problem is probably related to the schema of the destination table. Can you provide a table ID or a query job id for further investigation?

Comment: Thank you. The Schema is being created ad-hoc from the query and does not exists beforehand. queryID : hallowed-forge-577:job_8ykkfC3YBnMjJwA-lJ_EO7HHYyE

Comment: I looked into the details of your particular query, and identified an internal bug when allowLargeResults is enabled. I've updated the answer to describe the details, but you may can get good results today if you disable allowLargeResults. Will this work for you?

Comment: Another temporary workaround would be to change the 'profile' identifier to any other name.

Comment: The core bug has been identified and fixed, and will go out in our next release next week.